# linkerd, kubernetes and dtab

Tags: routes, kubernetes, linkerd

I'am very new to linkerd in Kubernetes, and I don't feel very comfortable with dtab and routing.

I followed this quite easy "getting started guide" step by step : https://blog.buoyant.io/2016/10/04/a-service-mesh-for-kubernetes-part-i-top-line-service-metrics/

Everything works fine, but it does not give deep explanations on how the whole thing is working.

So, I have these "incoming" rules :

`/srv=>/#/io.l5d.k8s/default/http;
/host=>/srv;
/svc=>/host;
/host/world=>/srv/world-v1`

In the tutorial, to test that it works, I need to make this curl request :

`$ http_proxy=$INGRESS_LB:4140 curl -s http://hello`

.. and it works! But I don't really know how my `http://hello` became a `/svc/hello` ... how and where this magic happened?

I see that the "default" namespace is "hardcoded" in `/#/io.l5d.k8s/default/http`, so I suppose that I cannot reach a service located in another namespace. How can I udpate the rules to do such a thing?

Thank you to help me progress with linkerd ^^

Comment: https://medium.com/@aerokite/configure-linkerd-for-your-application-running-in-kubernetes-fcac85fc4eda

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://linkerd.io/1/advanced/routing/) you can find documentation about how `http://hello` becomes `/svc/hello`

Regarding accessing a service in a different namespace you can use something like `http://service.namespace` then have some dtabs so they eventually use the kubernetes service discovery namer `io.l5d.k8s` using the right namespace and service name. See [this](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd/blob/master/linkerd/docs/namer.md) for more informaiton